What is the relationship between electron-phonon coupling and nonadiabatic effects?
We know that under the Born-Oppenheimer (BO) approximation, the motion of nuclei and electrons is decoupled. However, when there is a degeneracy between potential energy surfaces, the nonadiabatic coupling term (electron-vibration coupling term) can no longer be neglected, and the BO approximation breaks down, leading to nonadiabatic effects. In my understanding, electron-phonon coupling in solids should be similar to the electron-vibration coupling (vibronic coupling) mentioned here, and its strength is an indicator of the magnitude of nonadiabatic effects in a system. When we consider electron-phonon coupling, we are, in fact, already going beyond the BO approximation. However, I have seen in some literature the expression "nonadiabatic electron-phonon coupling," where it is mentioned that nonadiabatic effects can modify the strength of the electron-phonon coupling. I don’t quite understand what this modification refers to, nor do I understand why nonadiabatic effects would modify their own descriptor. I have also not come across a similar expression like "nonadiabatic vibronic coupling" in molecular system research. Since I have only recently started learning about electron-phonon coupling, my understanding may be incorrect in some areas, so I welcome any corrections. Below is the literature I found that mentions non-adiabatic electron-phonon coupling: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.105.224311

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE.
